# PHP variable not being passed to page "loaded" with ajax

Tags: php, jquery

I have a page (parent) that when a button (with .click funciton) is clicked it uses jQuery .load to load a form into the div. On the parent page is the following PHP

```
<?php
   $SubmitDATETIME = date("n/j/Y g:i A");
   $timestamp = date ("n/Y");
?>
```

the "loaded" content uses a remote script to validate the form, but I cannot seem to pass the $SubmitDATETIME and $timestamp to the loaded form. I've tried just using input boxes like

`<input type"text" value="<?php echo $SubmitDATETIME ?>">` but they are empty. When I put same code on parent page it works. Should I a) create this function with JS and apply to the button's click funciton, or b)is there a way to pass the $SubmitDATETIME and $timestamp variables from the parent page to the loaded content? possibly make it a remote PHP function and use .get to echo the values? I'm stumped.

thx

*************************** EDIT *********************************

I might not have been as clear as I needed to be on this, when you click the "button" it invokes a click function `$("#singleContent").load('pForm.php #formContent', function() {...});` inside the function is the validation for the form, which contains the submtiHandler. In the submitHandler is a function to build an xml string of all the values of the form. One of which was to "echo the submitDATETIME" php function. this is where i was having issues. When I included the function as a $_SESSION, i could get it to print to the loaded form, but the validation was not echoing it. I know that I could use JS to build the funciton in the validation, but I don't know how. I was able to echo the submitDATETIME to a hidden input and get it's value from that in the xml string. phew. Is there a better way? how would I build the datetime with JS?

Comment: Javascript has its own date API: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp .. why can't you use that?

Comment: can't get it to format the same way, has to be formatted the same way for backend WCF service. pls help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to put those variables to the $_SESSION array.

on the parent page:

```
<?php
   $SubmitDATETIME = date("n/j/Y g:i A");
   $timestamp = date ("n/Y");
   session_start();
   $_SESSION['timestamp'] = $timestamp;
   $_SESSION['submitDATETIME'] = $SubmitDATETIME;
?>
```

in the ajax loaded form:

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
<input type"text" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['submitDATETIME']  ?>">
```

Comment: you got me going in right direction, had to echo "$_SESSION['submitDATETIME'] into a hidden input and add the value to the click string like <DATETIME>" + $('[name=date]').val() + "</DATETIME> I guess because the validation was loaded with the click function the value was getting lost?

Comment: I don't really know where it's lost. I would have to see a little bit more of your code.

Comment: here is a snippet of the click function, which is called when the content is loaded. ... '<DATETIME><?php echo $_SESSION['submitDATETIME']  ?></DATETIME>'... I have the parent page and loaded page as you have above. The only way I can get it to work is to have a hidden input (name=date) with the vale and then in the click funciton "<DATETIME>" + $('[name=date]').val() + "</DATETIME>"

Answer (score 0):

make sure input is paced after php code, rest every thing is fine

Answer (score 0):

If the page is already loaded, then you must inform Javascript of the variable sent by PHP. The following code uses PHP to output date values *into* Javascript strings that can be used later on the page with Javascript.

```
// Javascript with embedded PHP:
var submitDATETIME = "<?php echo date("n/j/Y g:i A"); ?>";
var timestamp = "<?php echo date("n/Y"); ?>";
var someOtherString = "<?php echo "hello world from PHP";?>";
```

Right now, these values will both be plain strings in Javascript.  If you need to make them into true Date() objects, [see the Javascript Date() reference.](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp)

Now, as a commenter said above, Javascript's own `Date()` object will do these same things. But if you need to pass other strings from PHP into Javascript, this will work.

Comment: can't get the JS DATE() to format in the correct order. sucks. Pls see EDIT